# CSS Skew - Get the Offset/Upper Distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

i need some help here. I have rectangle (red). This rectangle has

```
transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
```

What i now need is the height of the area above the red. Look at the image:

[image]

Im Sure that this is simple math. but i dont find a soloution on google...

Thank you^^

**EDIT: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raROPy**

Comment: u need exactly the above image right??

Comment: You want this height (in a variable) and use it for something, or just want to know what the height is?

Comment: @Rvervuurt in the div, with the transform" inside is an img. and i need the value for top. if use top 0 there is a gap at the top.

Comment: Can you please explain the end result you are looking. Also, you [shouldn't use `skew()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew) you should use `skewX(0) skewY(-6deg)`

Comment: @web-tiki take a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raROPy   here you see that the image has absolute top: 0, but there is still a gap top the top. i need the negative offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to fill the top right red gap with the "unskewed" content, you should set the [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) of the content to the top right with :

```
transform-origin: 100% 0;
```

rather than using absolute positioning and a negative top value :

```css
#container {
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img-container {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: skewY(6deg);
}
#img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-9.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get that height mathematically you just need to use the tan function:

```
tan(θ) = Opposite / Adjacent
```

You take the tan of your skew angle (in this case 6deg) and multiply it with the Adjacent (in this case half of your box with) and you get the Opposite.
So:

```
height = tan(6) * boxwidth/2
```

For further reference check [mathisfun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-side-right-triangle.html)

If you use less or scss (with compass) you can actually get that without js:

SCSS with Compass:

```
$width: 652px;
$angle: 6deg;

$skewheight: tan($angle)*$width/2;
```

Here's the JS version in your Codepen example:
http://codepen.io/MrBambule/pen/vEPVZG